# Is there a library or something for org-mode that let's me make traversal more VIM like, without fully using Evil?

Tags: org-mode, navigation

I'd like to navigate in my org-mode files sometimes using just the home row, but other times I'm perfectly ok with the full emacs default key-bindings for org-mode.  For instance, when everything is folded, I'd like to just use `j` or `k` for up and down since I only want to navigate up to the correct headline to tab it open.  I realize I could just do a ace-jump, or search, or something, but I'm curious if there already exists something that makes this VIM like navigation possible?  Also, I don't think I'm ready to go full evil-mode yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Org itself brings such a feature, which you could expand.

You have to setup your org-mode a bit, because this keymap is auto-generated on every call to the function. Also you need to disable the auto isearch feature to navitage. see following source:

```
(setq org-goto-auto-isearch nil)

(advice-add 'org-goto-map :after (lambda ()
                                   (org-defkey org-goto-map "k" 'outline-next-visible-heading)
                                   (org-defkey org-goto-map "j" 'outline-previous-visible-heading)))
```

Use this feature by using `C-c C-j` or calling `M-x org-goto`.

---

There are also other, more universal ways to easily set up those keybindings, without going vi-style, those work also for other parts of Emacs:

- [Hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra)
- [General](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el)

Org-mode defines functions:
`org-next-visible-heading` and `org-previous-visible-heading`, which you could bind with above mentioned packages.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [worf](https://github.com/abo-abo/worf) package by abo-abo that does something like this.

Answer (score 2):

In my org mode (9.5.2), the following adjustment of Jue's answer worked:

```
(setq org-goto-auto-isearch nil)

(advice-add 'org-goto--set-map :after (lambda ()
  (org-defkey org-goto-map "k" 'outline-next-visible-heading)
  (org-defkey org-goto-map "j" 'outline-previous-visible-heading)))
```